# Customize \ answerline in Exam class

Tags: exam

I would like to create a quiz item that resembles this example:

```
____ 1. (p. 63) In a grouped frequency distribution, the mode falls in the most 
   frequently occurring class interval, more specifically, at its

 -  a. upper nominal limit
 -  b. lower nominal limit
 -  c. upper real limit
 -  d. midpoint.
```

When using the Exam class, I am unable to insert an \answerline next to the question number.  An example of my code follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,answers]{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question (p. 63) In a grouped frequency distribution, the mode falls in the most
   frequently occurring class interval, more specifically, at its
\begin{choices}
\choice upper nominal limit
\choice lower nominal limit
\choice upper real limit
\choice midpoint
\end{choices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can customize the `\questionlabel` to get the same affect:

```
\renewcommand\questionlabel{\rule{0.25in}{0.5pt}\thequestion. }
```

The downside to this is that answers won't print out if you require that feature.

Comment: Excellent.  Knowing what to search for in the documentation helps a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Here's sort of an ugly, bludgeoned version of \answerline which accomplishes what you're looking for, and ALSO works with printing out the solutions. I'm trying to do this same thing, so any improvements to this would be appreciated.

```
\renewcommand\answerline[1][{}]{
  \ifx\@queslevel\ques@ref
    \let\ans@l=\questionlabel
  \else
    \ifx\@queslevel\part@ref
      \let\ans@l=\partlabel
    \else
      \ifx\@queslevel\subpart@ref
        \let\ans@l=\subpartlabel
      \else
        \ifx\@queslevel\subsubpart@ref
          \let\ans@l=\subsubpartlabel
        \else
          \def\ans@l{}
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \par \vspace{-35pt}
  \ifprintanswers
    \hspace{-20mm}
    \mbox{
      \parbox[c][20pt][c]{\answerlinelength}{
        \center
        {\LARGE\bfseries #1}
        \rule{\answerlinelength}{.4pt}
      }
    }\vspace{15pt}
  \else
    \hspace{-20mm}
    \mbox{
      \parbox[c][20pt][c]{\answerlinelength}{
        \center
        {\LARGE\bfseries \color{white} X} % X for correct v-spacing
        \rule{\answerlinelength}{.4pt}
      }
    }\vspace{15pt}
  \fi
  \par
}
```